MongoDB EF Core provider creates duplicate collection items during loading of root object
I am using the MongoDB EF Core provider and I am getting duplicates for embedded collections of complex objects when I load the root object. I have noticed this with latest version 8.0 and previous 7.0.0-preview.1. I am using .net8. This is my .proj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Here is the sample which triggers the bug:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;

var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_URL");
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = MflixDbContext.Create(client.GetDatabase("sample"));

var movie1 = new Movie();
movie1._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
movie1.title = "Movie 1";
movie1.actors.Add(new Actor() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });
movie1.actors.Add(new Actor() { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Smith" });
db.Movies.Add(movie1);
Console.WriteLine("Total actors going to the database: " + movie1.actors.Count());
db.SaveChanges();

var movieFromDb = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x._id == movie1._id);
Console.WriteLine("Movie: " + movieFromDb.title);
Console.WriteLine("Total actors after loading from database: " + movieFromDb.actors.Count());

internal class MflixDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; init; }
    public static MflixDbContext Create(IMongoDatabase database) =>
        new(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MflixDbContext>()
            .UseMongoDB(database.Client, database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName)
            .Options);
    public MflixDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().ToCollection("movies");
    }
}

internal class Actor
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}

internal class Movie
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> actors { get; set; } = new List<Actor>();
}

If you run, you will get the following output:

Total actors going to the database: 2
Movie: Movie 1
Total actors after loading from database: 4

If you look at the "movies" collection in mongodb, you will find no duplicates:
sample> db.movies.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66396aa29571e499f39d6fab'),
    title: 'Movie 1',
    actors: [
      { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Smith' },
      { FirstName: 'Mary', LastName: 'Smith' }
    ]
  }
]

I hope I am doing something wrong because this is a pretty big bug to be released. While 7.0.0 was preview release, 8.0 is not a preview release but a general release.
I have also noticed situations where only a portion of the children items are duplicated, instead of all of them.
Can anyone confirm they are having this issue? I will post this in the MongoDB forums also.

At it's core EF is an ORM meant to bridge the gap to Relational database models. Mongo is a document store. EF internally uses a tracking cache for entities that are tracked, either through adding or reading. The issue looks like after you add the actors via the new movie, the DbContext is tracking those references, however when you read the movie again, it is counting those tracked references plus new references for the rows that were written (and read again) from the database.
Normally within an EF entity, if you want related child entities (movie.actors) you would need to explicitly request them using .Include(x => x.Actors) With a document store, the Actors are stored as part of the Movie so I doubt this is a requirement for Mongo, but it may conflict with how the provider and EF is handling references. The crux of the problem is that your Actor does not have a PK defined. This is a pretty strong requirement for a relational DB and helps EF ensure that tracked references and data read from the DB can be matched up. It might work if you define a PK for the actor, even if its the combination of First and Last name.
Alternatively I would suggest is avoiding using the same DbContext instance for both a Write and a Read. I suspect the following scenario would work properly: (Note: DbContext instances should always be disposed)
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_URL");
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

var movie1 = new Movie();
movie1._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
movie1.title = "Movie 1";
movie1.actors.Add(new Actor() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });
movie1.actors.Add(new Actor() { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Smith" });

using (var db = MflixDbContext.Create(client.GetDatabase("sample")))
{
    db.Movies.Add(movie1);
    Console.WriteLine("Total actors going to the database: " + movie1.actors.Count());
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = MflixDbContext.Create(client.GetDatabase("sample")))
{
    var movieFromDb = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x._id == movie1._id);
    Console.WriteLine("Movie: " + movieFromDb.title);
    Console.WriteLine("Total actors after loading from database: " + movieFromDb.actors.Count());
}

I suspect there is a bug in the Mongo provider, or it is directly tied to the lack of a PK on the entity, but it might not be a very simple thing to resolve since it is really going against exactly what EF was designed to bridge. An Actor in a relational database represents a single row in an Actors table. EF will expect, and work to ensure that two or more Movies that reference that actor and get that actor entity back with the respective movies are given the exact same object reference that the DbContext tracks. Where within a document store, an Actor is an owned independent instance for that Movie document. If instances are intended to be shared in a document store that would probably have unexpected consequences when reading and updating data even if a PK "fixes" the behaviour since each movie document could contain different Actor data for the same PK value. (Not allowed in a relational database.)

I see what you are saying. Feels like EF might be designed too relationally-oriented and trying to use it on something as dynamic as an document model has all kinds of quirks. As for my project which I started and used the EF Core provider, I think I am going to convert it to just using their CSharp driver. It is very simple to use (as least based on documentation) I tried my example using the driver and there no issues with duplications.

It also worries me that the designers of that provider did not catch this issue in their tests. Its definitely not an edge case!

It is a bit of an odd one to try and build a provider for a document data store into an Object "Relational" Manager. :)  I think what they really want is just a Linq wrapper for the document store.
